# failed to catch duplicate error

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

```
from pymongo.errors import DuplicateKeyError

def insert_duplicate_token(self):
        try:                       
            fields = ..
            token = Token.create_a_new_document(fields)
            token.save()
            token = Token.create_a_new_document(fields)
            token.save()

            self.logger.info('success')

        except DuplicateKeyError:
            self.logger.exception('Duplicate caught')

        except Exception, err:
            self.logger.exception('failed...')
            return False
```

The error raised is 
    u'Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error collection: oauth_test.tokens index: idx_access_token dup key: { : "gRULKp6sqPWRYDrJNrvaifMhlaC8qvzfZOpqTZLTPxHnQ691vT" })'

but is caught in `Exception`, and not in `DuplicateKeyError`

tried

```
import pymongo
pymongo.errors - does not exists
```

here is the `stacktrace`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "move_invalid_tokens_worker.py", line 91, in insert_duplicate_token
    token.save()
  File "/Users/ohadperry/.virtualenvs/oauth/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 386, in save
    raise NotUniqueError(message % unicode(err))
NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error collection: oauth_test.tokens index: access_token_1 dup key: { : "MIeJey0f3rWkedMZacDIjDMB3a04ilrbdieKaZ2BWt0lI0sATP" })
```

weird..

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback please?

Comment: added to the question body

Answer (score 3):

I answered myself with the stackstrace, thanks @Arount

```
from pymongo.errors import DuplicateKeyError
from mongoengine import NotUniqueError 

def insert_duplicate_token(self):
        try:                       
            fields = ..
            token = Token.create_a_new_document(fields)
            token.save()
            token = Token.create_a_new_document(fields)
            token.save()

            self.logger.info('success')

        except (NotUniqueError, DuplicateKeyError), error:
            self.logger.exception('Duplicate caught')

        except Exception, error:
            self.logger.exception('failed...')
            return False
```

Comment: Since I'm here, for future users, it's looks like `DuplicateKeyError` refer to `_id` field ("primary key" already exists), while `NotUniqueError` refer to a unique index rule. That is why 2 different exception exists.